# How to echo a variable without expansion using a makefile

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, echo

I am using make and am having a make file help me build an rpm using [rpm-builder](https://code.google.com/p/rpmbuilder/wiki/README). Where as you have to make an `rpm.properties` file with the following layout.

```
  rpm_name=my_app
  rpm_version=1.0
  rpm_release=$(date +%s)
  rpm_summary=${rpm_name}
  rpm_install_dir=/projects/my_app/webapps
  files=src/my_application.properties,log4j.xml
```

This is the part of the makefile I am using to do this

```
rpm:
    @echo rpm_name=foo > rpm.properties
    @echo rpm_version=1.0 >> rpm.properties
    @echo rpm_release=$(date +%s) >> rpm.properties
    @echo rpm_summary=foo >> rpm.properties
    @echo rpm_install_dir=~/foo_install >> rpm.properties 
    @echo file=foo.class >> rpm.properties
    @echo rpm_install_post_script_file=foo.sh >> rpm.properties
    @echo rpm_username=root >> rpm.properties
    @echo rpm_groupname=root >> rpm.properties
```

The make file works correctly expect for the line with,

`@echo rpm_release=$(date +%s) >> rpm.properties`

Which does not output to the `rpm.properties` file. The `rpm.properties` outputs as follows

```
rpm_name=foo
rpm_version=1.0
rpm_release=
rpm_summary=foo
rpm_install_dir=~/foo_install
file=foo.class
rpm_install_post_script_file=foo.sh
rpm_username=root
rpm_groupname=root
```

While I am looking for

```
rpm_name=foo
rpm_version=1.0
rpm_release=$(date +%s)
rpm_summary=foo
rpm_install_dir=~/foo_install
file=foo.class
rpm_install_post_script_file=foo.sh
rpm_username=root
rpm_groupname=root
```

Does anyone know how I would output a a line of text that is interpreted by the make file as a variable like `$(date +%s)` is being as plain text non expanded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` from make. You then also need to escape the `$` from the shell.

Use:

```
@echo rpm_release='$$(date +%s)' >> rpm.properties
```

Also you can do all of that with one `echo`/`printf` and a single redirection instead of multiples if you want to.

Comment: that worked thanks, I knew I had to escape the characters somehow but am not too familiar with make to do so.